# Query with exclusion

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query finding all the salespersons names that do not have orders with a company.

The query I have is:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Salesperson
JOIN Orders ON orders.salesperson_id = Salesperson.ID
    WHERE cust_id <> 4
GROUP BY Name;
```

While this somewhat works, I feel that I should be more explicit. If you could help guide me to where I am going wrong, I'd appreciate the help. What I am expecting to see is...

```
Abe
Chris
Dan
Joe
```

The tables are:

SalesPerson

```
ID    Name    Age    Salary
1   Abe 61  140000
2   Bob 34  44000
5   Chris   34  40000
7   Dan 41  52000
8   Ken 57  115000
11  Joe 38  38000
```

Customer

```
ID    Name    City    Industry
4   Samsonic    plesant J
6   Panasung    oaktown J
7   Samony  Jackson B
9   Orange  Jackson B
```

Orders

```
Number    Date    cust_id    salesperson_id    amount
10  1996-08-02  4   2   540
20  1999-01-30  4   8   1800
30  1995-07-14  9   1   460
40  1998-01-29  7   2   2400
50  1998-02-03  6   7   600
60  1998-03-02  6   7   720
70  1998-05-06  9   7   150
```

Comment: What sort of result are you getting now? I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm seeing Abe, Bob, Dan but think that Bob should be excluded since they have an order with that company and I think the results should be Abe, Chris, Dan, Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining together those two tables, you get only the ids which show up in both tables and whose `cust_id` value is not 4, since your join is not an `OUTER JOIN`, i.e. `ids = 1, 2, 7`.

Then, when you state `SELECT Name`, you obtain this:

```
Abe   // id = 1
Bob   // id = 2
Dan   // id = 7
```

(The `GROUP BY` statement is completely useless in this case, since you do not use any `COUNT(...)`, `SUM(...)` or similar in the `SELECT`)

If you want to avoid repetition, you can replace the `GROUP BY` statement using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`.

From the result you're expecting, I suppose you want to exclude all the ids of SalesPerson who made an order with `cust_id = 4`.

This should work smoothly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM SalesPerson
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT salesperson_id FROM Orders WHERE cust_id = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniele, this worked well. I had not thought of a sub-select exclusion.

Comment: Note: MySQL often implements distinct under the hood using `GROUP BY`, so using `GROUP BY` certainly would not be "useless."